# Клиент-сервер SSL на C#

Tags: c#, ssl

Дали в универе такое задание:

`"Реализовать защищенное взаимодействие в архитектуре клиент-сервер, где принцип защищённого взаимодействия основан на использовании протокола SSL2."`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в C# стандартные классы, реализующие SSL?

Дайте, хотя бы, отправную точку,.. с чего начать,.. а то на просторах интернета все уж слишком разбросано... Ну, если Вам будет не сложно, то и от маленького примера я не откажусь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SslStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) класс. Там же есть и примеры. Вам понадобиться сгенерировать самоподписанный сертификат. Обычно это делают через openssl (который придется скачать отдельно), например вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl

Answer (score 3):

`TcpClient` и `SslStream`.

Сначала открываете соединение:

```
client = new TcpClient();
client.BeginConnect(ipAddress, port, OnSocketConnected, null);

private void OnSocketConnected(IAsyncResult ar){
    if (mClient.Connected){
            Auth();
    }
    else{
        mClient.EndConnect(ar);
    }
}
```

При успехе защищённое соединение настраиваете:

```
private void Auth(){
    sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(),
        false,
        ValidateServerCertificate,
        null
        );

    sslStream .BeginAuthenticateAsClient(adress, ar =>{
        if (!mSslStream.IsAuthenticated){
            client.Close();
        }
        else{
            sslStream.BeginRead(mRecieveBuffer, 0, 4096, ReceiveCallback, null);
        }
    }, null);

}
```

Это, если очень-очень кратко. Можно на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) почитать официальный туториал.

Comment: Только нужно выставить `sslStream.SslProtocol = SslProtocols.Ssl2`, а то там SSL3 / TLS 1 по умолчанию